# Passing back values from a dialog prompt to update spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-engine

Google sheets is new to me as is JavaScript. I've read a lot of Google examples. I've attempted to follow them, but without success.

I have a spread sheet that I use to track my son's allowance and spending. I've managed to get it to auto populate his weekly allowance and I can transfer funds to this 'college' account, but that's because the Prompt function works and these two features only require a single parameter. Now I need three such parameters and as such I need to branch out beyond the simple prompt.

Depending on which example I follow, the dialog will close when the submit button is clicked --that doesn't happen with this iteration-- but I've never gotten the call to insertGame to work. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. However, know that I am a scripting novice, and as such require more explanation than most.

---

Code.gs

```
function BuyAGame_()
{
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('GamePurchase')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'My custom dialog');
}

function insertGame(form){
  var Value = form.Price;
  if(form.Refund)
    Value = Value * -1;
  InsertNewTransactionOnDemandAccount( new Date(), Value, form.Name, 'normal', 'italic', "Game", null );
}
```

---

GamePurchase.html

```
<script>
function Close()
{
  google.script.run.insertGame(document.getElementById('myForm'));
  google.script.host.close();
}
</script>
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
  Game Name:<input type="text" name="Name"><br>
  Game Price:<input type="text" name="Price"><br>
  Is this a refund?<input type="checkbox" name="Refund" value="Refund"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="Close()" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the function Close(). From that function, call the handling function in the code.gs file directly. The form object, or really anything can be passed back. Then call .host.close() in order to close the html dialog.

google.script.ru,

```
function Close()
{
  google.script.run.insertGame(document.getElementById('myForm'));
  google.script.host.close();
}
```